# how do I limit the available languages in the device language settings?

Tags: android, build, localization

I build the android 7 source code and flashed to my board,i am able to see lot of languages in language selection.Now I want to limit the number of language like (US-English,UK-English,Spanish,Arabic only out of 240 languages) in Language selection.

How can i modify my android 7 source code to limit the available languages in the listview?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: for example  if I want to distribute my device in NorhAmerica,I don't want to show other language which are not used by northAmericans

Comment: you need to root your device for that, find the languages from systems / settings / framework one of this apk's then decompile it  make you changes and then build apk again and push it to device. again this will be device specific ( i.e model no.) againn later if you want to roll out from same model you can create flashable zip and flash it via some custom recovery ( cwm / twrp)

Comment: I am using freescale board as my device,i  am building the whole android 7 source code specific to board with Board support package(BSP) and flashing it.in Source code perspective where i can to find available language list and then I can edit available language list to show only few languages in device language settings.

Comment: you can always give it a try, once you remove them from respective apk i don't think they will not be visible for user.

Comment: tried that,no success